# How To Access Declared Variable in .aspx File Inside <asp> Tag Element?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've have code below :

```
<div class="row">
<%
    foreach (Product product in products)
    {
%>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <asp:LinkButton 
        class="card df gdc aic"
        OnClick="btnDetail_Click"
        ID="btnDetail" 
        runat="server">

        <%= product.Name %>

    </asp:LinkButton>
</div>
<%
    }
%>
```

The code `<%= product.Name %>` produce an error that say, The name `product` does not exist int the current context.

How to access that `product` variable ?

Comment: Better use a Repeater Control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do that using a LinkButton. It would work with a normal HTML link though. You should use a Repeater instead:

```html
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="productsList">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <asp:LinkButton 
                class="card df gdc aic"
                ID="btnDetail" 
                runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'>
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

```cs
productsList.DataSource = products;
productsList.DataBind();
```